# Lodash flatMap to flatten object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following object:

```
const arr = [{
 "@id": "6005752",
 employeeId: {
  id: "22826"
},
allocationIntervals: {
 jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval: {
  "@id": "34430743",
   startTime: "2017-03-15T01:50:00.000Z",
   endTime: "2017-03-15T02:50:00.000Z"
 },
   "@id": "34430756",
   startTime: "2017-04-16T02:50:00.000Z",
   endTime: "2017-04-16T03:50:00.000Z"
},
taskId: {
 id: "16465169"
}
}];
```

I am trying to pull out all of the start and end times from allocationIntervals.jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval to create something like the following:

```
const arr = [{
  employeeId: "22826",
  taskId: "16465169"
  startTime: "2017-03-15T01:50:00.000Z",
  endTime: "2017-03-15T02:50:00.000Z"
  },
  {
  employeeId: "22826",
  taskId: "16465169",
  startTime: "2017-04-16T02:50:00.000Z",
  endTime: "2017-04-16T03:50:00.000Z"   
}];
```

I'm looking at doing this with Lodash flatMap, with something like the following function:

```
const result = _.flatMap(arr, item => {
  return _.map(item.allocationIntervals, allocation => _.defaults({ start: item.jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval.startTime }, allocation));
});
```

Does anyone know of a way to solve the above?

Comment: Can you correct the data structure that you have there to put brackets around the arrays? It's a bit unclear whether `allocationIntervals` or `jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval` is the array.

Comment: Sorry! - I have updated with square brackets wrapping the original. This is how the array is returning from an API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like for every item in `arr` you need 2 elements in the output array; one for `allocationIntervals` and one for `allocationIntervals.jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval`. Each one has the same `employeeId` and `taskId` from the item itself.

Create a function that will return an output item given an item and an allocation:

```
const createAllocation = (item, allocation) => ({
    employeeId: item.employeeId.id, 
    taskId: item.taskId.id, 
    startTime: allocation.startTime, 
    endTime: allocation.endTime
});
```

Call this function twice for each item passing the `allocationIntervals` for the first call and `allocationIntervals.jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval` for the second call:

```
const result = _.flatMap(arr, item => [
    createAllocation(item, item.allocationIntervals), 
    createAllocation(item, item.allocationIntervals.jobTaskTimeAllocationInterval)
]);
```